# How to find a nodeid for certain folder?

Tags: alfresco

Junior developer here. I've been trying make a method that checks that a certain path exist and checks the nodeId of the last folder of the past. For example company_home/hr/junior_developer. I mean I need to find what is the nodeId of the junior_developer folder. I've been trying with this https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/API-JS-findNode.html but I am unable to make this work. Could someone help me?

Comment: Where do you want this code to run? In the browser? In Share? In the Repo? In an activiti workflow? On a different server?

Comment: Oh sorry, that's pretty vital information to know. I'd like get the information in to the browsers console.log.

And the application that requires this feature is a customised one of Alfresco ADF.

Comment: You'll need to use the Alfresco REST API calls to do it then. The docs you've linked to only apply to JS running on the Alfresco repo itself (eg repo webscript). What version of Alfresco are you targetting? (The new REST API is pretty nice, but that only helps if your Alfresco is new enough to have it!)

Comment: I think the version is 5.2

Comment: I had to check, it's 5.2.

Comment: If someone else is having this same problem, the answer is here https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/queries/findNodes . Thank you @Gagravarr for pointing me to the right direction!